# Can I get Meta sites on my combined flair?

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, flair, combined-flair

I have a good idea of what my top SE site is. I have a large base of answers, a few that are high-scoring, a lot of badges, and I'm <s>a few answers away from</s> *have* my first tag badge. I even have the Mortarboard badge.

Only one problem: it's Meta Stack Overflow. It will never be counted on my combined flair.

I can already get per-site flair for MSO:

[image: profile for Stephen Leppik at Meta Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

But it still won't show up on my combined flair:
[image: profile for Stephen Leppik on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I'd like to see one or more of the following implemented, in order of importance:

- My badges on per-site Metas (where I have 200+ Meta-pseudo-rep) added to the badge count in combined flair.
- Per-site Metas showing up in the icons based on Meta-pseudo-rep.
- Meta-pseudo-rep (from sites where it's 200+) added to my combined flair. (I'd be perfectly fine without this.)

Comment: Like, as punishment? A "Scarlet Letter" type of thing?

Comment: @Shog9 what? Why would it be "punishment"?

Comment: It'd just duplicate the icons (in greyscale) for all of your normal sites, potentially pushing some of them off the list.

Comment: @Shog9 fair enough, I guess—I mostly just want acknowledgement that I'm active on Meta.SO, because the only count by which MSO isn't my most active site is by Olympics-style ranking via badges.

Comment: Trivia: if per-site meta reputation was separate from the main site, your MSO reputation would be 3597

Comment: @Shog9 did you just have a SEDE query or something lying around for exactly that purpose?

Comment: Well, I have access to the internal data, so I can calculate your site rep for any site on a whim. But as it happens... [There are cupcakes for everyone.](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/215919/virtual-meta-reputation-for-user-x?UserId=6388243)

Comment: And it's about 300 over because I hit the rep cap 6 times… I note that it also can't account for some sources of rep gain/loss, such as downvoting an answer, and that it just flat-out ignores some others, such as accepting someone else's answer to your question, or that you don't earn anything for accepting your own answer.

Comment: @Shog9 I ran the data and my MSO rep would be 26945, twice as much as my current global total :( I wish it was real now...